# Json Issues on MVC 2

Tags: json

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#deceasedmonths").change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '<%=Url.Action("ArchiveList", "Deceased","POST")%>',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { month: $("#deceasedmonths :selected").val() },
                success: function (response) {
                var markup = "<div><tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Gender</th><th>Date     of Death</th></tr></div>";
                    for (var x = 0; x < response.length; x++) {
                        var val = response[x].split(",");
                        markup += "<tr><td>" + val[0] + "</td><td>" + val[1] + "</td><td>" + val[2]                     + "</td><td>" + val[3] + "</td></tr>";
                    };
                    $("#archivelistdeceasedgridview").html(markup).show();
                }
            })
        });
    });
```

I have the above code to return a Json from an MVC 2 controller. The code works in firefox, but not in Internet explorer. Can someone assist...
Thanks

Comment: Do you get any errors in IE develop console (F12)?

Comment: got this error message: SEC7115: :visited and :link styles can only differ by color. Some styles were not applied to :visited.